# afxdb.h error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I'm writing a *dll in c++ to connect to database. I tried using afxdb.h in my console application and it works fine. Now, I want to use the same code in my *dll. So, I added afxdb.h to stdafx.h and when I compiled gave me this error

```
mfcs42d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in JunkDLL.obj
mfcs42d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : warning LNK4006: _DllMain@12 already defined in JunkDLL.obj; second definition ignored
Creating library Debug/JunkDLL.lib and object Debug/JunkDLL.exp
Debug/JunkDLL.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

my stdafx.h looks like

```
#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__123__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H__123__INCLUDED_
#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#include "afxwin.h"
#include "afxext.h"
#include "afxdb.h"
// Insert your headers here
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN// Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include "windows.h"
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the  previous line.
#endif // !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__123__INCLUDED_)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DLL is [statically linked to MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea.aspx). In this situation, MFC provides its own `DllMain()` entry point, and your DLL should not provide one.

You can either perform initialization in the `InitInstance()` method of a [CWinApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx)-derived singleton, or [dynamically link your DLL to MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c674tx.aspx).

Comment: So I commented out BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(...) from JunkDLL.cpp and compiled without any errors. Is it the right way to do this ? I'm new to c++ ( VC 6 ).

Comment: If your `DllMain()` was not responsible for any initialization or termination actions (i.e. if it was empty), then it's the right thing to do indeed. (As a personal preference, I would suggest removing the function instead of commenting it out, as dead code in comments results in noise that makes your module harder to understand and maintain.)

Comment: The *.dll is intented to be a Data Access Layer accessed by multiple threads. I'm not sure if DLLMain() will be necessary in that case.

Comment: Depends on your code. If you end up requiring global initialization or termination, you will have to follow the `CWinApp` route. As of now, is your `DllMain()` actually doing anything? (If it is, can you add that code to your question?)